# collecting data from vscode extension

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, analytics, vscode-extensions, vscode-plugin

I am new to vscode extension development. I have developed a vscode extension and havent published it. its for internal use and users would be using this extension from vsix file.

I now want to collect usage data like - how many people are using this extension, what version of the extension, what version of node  they are using etc.

how can i do that? i have looked into vscode telemetry but looks like that mostly sending data to microsoft.

can the usage data be collected without publishing the plugin? if so, how?
if not, can it be done if we publish? how?

Comment: Send data to your server every time the extension is used

Comment: if you collect telemetry many users will not install it, make it very clear you collect telemetry on the README page

Answer (score 0):

The new Extension Telemetry API has been finalized in v1.75:

> The new `TelemetryLogger` API has been finalized. This API aims to
> make utilizing telemetry easier for the author and safer for the end
> user. The API enables things such as built-in secret cleaning, a
> telemetry output channel, error handlers, and automatic telemetry
> level management. This allows for a more cohesive telemetry experience
> that is guaranteeed to follow our requirements.

from v1.73 Release Notes:

> #### Extension Telemetry API
>
> To further drive telemetry best practices and enhance the telemetry
> features extensions have offered to them, this iteration introduces
> the proposed `telemetryLogger` API. This API allows extension to
> supply a `TelemetryAppender` which acts as the core sending logic
> (implemented utilizing [Application
> Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-new-resource)
> or another data recording service). This `TelemetryAppender` is then
> used to instantiate a `TelemetryLogger` which is the class which you
> should log telemetry through. The `TelemetryLogger` provides a shared
> output channel to see sent telemetry events, proper telemetry setting
> checks, and personally identifiable information cleaning. Additionally
> any errors thrown by utilizing the VS Code API will be logged to your
> appender for better error diagnostics. A simple sample can be found
> [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/d7dd9da34a9849396719408716d468512b5e5abb/telemetry-sample/src/extension.ts)
> and feedback can be provided
> [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/160090)